# Public member 'ToCSVValue' on type 'Integer' not found for VB Extension method

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

I am trying to write a ToCSV() extension in VB based on [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/?date=2010-02-04).  It could be that my C# to VB is not correct, but it all seems right.
I added a module with:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function ToCSV(Of T)(items As IEnumerable(Of T)) As String
    Try

        Dim csvBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        Dim properties = GetType(T).GetProperties()

        For Each item As T In items

            '' Test Code
            Dim newline As String = ""
            For Each l2 As Reflection.PropertyInfo In properties

                ' This works
                newline &= l2.GetValue(item, Nothing)

                ' This works too
                Dim int As Integer = 1234
                Dim s As String = int.ToCSVValue()

                'This works
                Dim nl = l2.GetValue(item, Nothing)

                ' This blows up with "Public member 'ToCSVValue' on type 'Integer' not found."  
                ' The Debugger type shows "Object {Integer}" which I assume to mean that the debugger interprets the object as an integer.
                nl = nl.ToCSVValue()
            Next

            ' Original code
            Dim line As String = String.Join(",", properties.Select(Function(p) p.GetValue(item, Nothing).ToCSVValue()).ToArray())
            csvBuilder.AppendLine(line)
        Next

        Return csvBuilder.ToString()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

End Function


<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Private Function ToCSVValue(Of T)(item As T) As String

    If item Is Nothing Then
        Return """"""
    End If

    If TypeOf item Is String Then
        Return String.Format("""{0}""", item.ToString().Replace("""", "\"""))
    End If
    Dim dummy As Double
    If Double.TryParse(item.ToString(), dummy) Then
        Return String.Format("{0}", item)
    End If
    Return String.Format("""{0}""", item)

End Function
```

When I call it with something like:

```
Dim s As String = ctx.Customers.Where(Function(x) x.CustomerID = 123456).Select(Function(x) New With {.CustomerID = x.CustomerID, .CustomerName = x.CustomerName}).ToCSV()
```

it gets to the function ToCSV just fine.  It recognizes the items passed in.  It pulls out the first item and sees that there are the 2 fields in it.  All good!

The GetValue() works just fine.

If I create a static integer and call ToCSVValue on it, it works fine.
If I create a static string and  call ToCSVValue on it, it works fine.

When I call ToCSVValue on the GetValue() I get:
Public member 'ToCSVValue' on type 'Integer' not found.

Likewise, if I have just strings in the dataset, I get:
Public member 'ToCSVValue' on type 'String' not found.

Ideally this would work as it is in the "Original code" section and I can kill all this other test code.

Can anyone tell me what is happening and why the "(Of T)" is not working the get GetValue() types, but it is for the directly cast types?

Comment: hmm .. not sure why, but it works if you use `ToCSVValue(nl)`

Comment: You are correct.  It does work like this.  But how can we get it to work as intended? `foo.ToCSV()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 'Option Infer On'.
When I use Option Infer On, it works fine.

If you don't use this, then VB is using 'Object' whenever you leave off the type.

Also, although this isn't causing your problem, the proper conversion of the ToCSV method is:

```
Public Function ToCSV(Of T As Class)(items As IEnumerable(Of T)) As String
```

Comment: It was a good shot, but same error.  It was previously on for the project as well.  I added it explicitly just to check and got the same error.

Comment: I see that adding "As Class" adds a constraint to the function.  I just don't know why it is needed or suggested.  Would you please explain?

Comment: @JustinTolchin: It must be because the author decided that this was only applicable for reference types and not value types.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that calling it as a method `ToCSVValue(p.GetValue(item, Nothing))` will work as in the C# version.

The longer answer is that you can't call extension methods on `Object` in VB. In VB `Object` is treated more like `dynamic` in C#. For example:

```
<Extension()> Function toStr(Of T)(item As T) As String
    Return item.ToString
End Function
```

then this will result in compile-time Warning "`Late bound resolution; runtime errors could occur.`" and a run-time Error "`Public member 'toStr' on type 'Integer' not found.`", but it will work in C#:

```
Dim i As Object = 123
Dim s = i.toStr
```